# Delete rabbitmq queues which start with particular name

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I am trying to delete rabbitmq queues in a particular vhost using kubectl command.
If I give below command I am able to delete the queue.

```
kubectl.exe exec -n kayaks svc/rabbitmq-ha -- rabbitmqctl --vhost=AM-Dev delete_queue 'TestDeletion'
```

But I want to delete a set of queues which all begin with some particular name like 'woms-'. How to accomplish the same. I tried below but it throws syntax error and I am unable to identify problem.

```
kubectl exec -n kayaks svc/rabbitmq-ha -- rabbitmqctl --vhost=AM-Dev eval 'IfUnused = false, IfEmpty = true,
MatchRegex = <<"^woms-">>, [rabbit_amqqueue:delete(Q, IfUnused, IfEmpty) || Q <- 
rabbit_amqqueue:list(), re:run(element(4, element(2, Q)), MatchRegex) 
=/= nomatch ].'
```

```
****kubectl : Error (argument validation): "syntax error before: '^'"
At line:1 char:1
+ kubectl exec -n kayaks svc/rabbitmq-ha -- rabbitmqctl --vhost=AM-Dev  ...****
```

Can someone guide me as to what is the mistake I am doing.

Comment: I am executing via kubectl command on a service. Note that  I can successfully delete a single queue by providing the queue name. My problem is I need to delete a set of queues with a particular prefix.

Comment: What about opening bash/sh session into container and executing your command from there? `kubectl exec -it -n kayaks svc/rabbitmq-ha /bin/sh`

Comment: I think you didnt understand my question. My problem is not executing the command. Because it works perfectly for a single queue. Issue is I want to execute many queues in single command.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying you can open a shell session into the container and then do: `rabbitmqctl --vhost=AM-Dev eval 'IfUnused = false, IfEmpty = true,
MatchRegex = <<"^woms-">>, [rabbit_amqqueue:delete(Q, IfUnused, IfEmpty) || Q <- 
rabbit_amqqueue:list(), re:run(element(4, element(2, Q)), MatchRegex) 
=/= nomatch ].' `

Comment: Are you saying the error I am facing is not because of a syntax error and its something else? Sorry but I am not very familiar with erlang.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster?